# Lipschitz function which fails to be differentiable on a dense set

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I'm trying to think of a function which is Lipschitz but which fails to be differentiable at a dense set of points. Of course, being a Lipschitz function it will be differentiable almost everywhere, but can we make it so that the function is not differentiable at every rational point (for instance)?

Comment: In his answer to the linked duplicate question, Dave L. Renfro gives an example of a function which satisfies the requirements of this question.